# Does specifying query to only match relevant documents speed up Elasticsearch aggregation request speed?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an Elasticsearch index. Every document in the index either has a field called "foobar" whose value is true, or does not have a field called "foobar" at all.

I expect both the following queries to return the same data. Is there any expected difference in efficiency between the following queries?

```
        size: 0,
        body: {
            query: {
                match: {
                    foobar: true
                }
            },
            aggs: {
                myaggregation: {
                    terms: {
                        field: "foobar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
        size: 0,
        body: {
            aggs: {
                myaggregation: {
                    terms: {
                        field: "foobar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i.e. should including the query match requirement speed up the query?